# Stretch image to div using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to stretch images in a carousel the entire width and height of the div that contains the carousel. However, the images are currently not occupying 100% width of the div, and the height is smaller or larger than the div. I am using Bootstrap 4.3.1. My code excerpt is shown below. Entire code is in this [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f3p1weob/1/) page.

```
<div class="row">

    <!-- card 1 -->
    <div class="col-sm-4 card" style="height: 350px">
        <div class="card-body small-tab-container">
            <h6 class="card-title">Activity (last 7 days)</h6>

            <p>Some content</p>

        </div>

    </div> <!-- end card 1 -->

    <!-- card 2 -->
    <div class="col-sm-4 card" style="height: 350px;">
        <div id="photoCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">

                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img src="https://media.wired.com/photos/5fb70f2ce7b75db783b7012c/master/pass/Gear-Photos-597589287.jpg" class="d-block img-fluid">
                </div>

                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/3680219/pexels-photo-3680219.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" class="d-block img-fluid">
                </div>

                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="https://www.cnet.com/a/img/-qQkzFVyOPEoBRS7K5kKS0GFDvk=/940x0/2020/04/16/7d6d8ed2-e10c-4f91-b2dd-74fae951c6d8/bazaart-edit-app.jpg" class="d-block img-fluid">
                </div>

                <!-- the below code will insert the previous and next photo arrows -->
                <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#photoCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>

                <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#photoCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>

            </div>
        </div> <!-- end carousel -->
    </div> <!-- end card 2 -->

    <!-- card 3 -->
    <div class="col-sm-4 card" style="Height: 350px">
        <div class="card-body small-tab-container">
            <h6 class="card-title">Upcoming Events</h6>

            <p>Some content</p>

        </div>
    </div> <!-- end card 3-->

</div> <!-- end: row 1 -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Your card `<div>`s still have their default padding,

Change all the `<div class="col-sm-4 card" ...>` to `<div class="col-sm-4 card p-0" ....>`.

or change the appropriate classes to include `padding: 0;`

Comment: Adding "p-0" class took care of the width/padding issue, thank you. It did not take care of the height, which is the more critical aspect for me. The images must be adjusted and fit into the size of the div. The image is overflowing the height of the div. See https://gattufamily.com/test.htm for an example.

Comment: add the `overflow-hidden` class to the same `<div class="col-sm-4 card p-0" ...>` blocks

Answer (score 0):

With some CSS the `object-fit` and `object-position` of the images, and adding some other bootstrap utility classes, I am able to make your images take up 100% height and width of your carousel container. Is this what you are looking for?

```css
.carousel-item img {
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Page title</h1>

    <div class="row">

        <!-- card 1 -->
        <div class="col-sm-4 card" style="height: 350px">
            <div class="card-body small-tab-container">
                <h6 class="card-title">Activity (last 7 days)</h6>

                <p>Some content</p>

            </div>

        </div> <!-- end card 1 -->

        <!-- card 2 -->
        <div class="col-sm-4 card p-0" style="height: 350px;">
            <div id="photoCarousel" class="carousel h-100 slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <div class="carousel-inner h-100">

                    <div class="carousel-item h-100 active">
                        <img src="https://media.wired.com/photos/5fb70f2ce7b75db783b7012c/master/pass/Gear-Photos-597589287.jpg" class="position-absolute t-0 l-0 h-100 w-100">
                    </div>

                    <div class="carousel-item h-100">
                        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/3680219/pexels-photo-3680219.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" class="position-absolute t-0 l-0 w-100 h-100">
                    </div>

                    <div class="carousel-item h-100">
                        <img src="https://www.cnet.com/a/img/-qQkzFVyOPEoBRS7K5kKS0GFDvk=/940x0/2020/04/16/7d6d8ed2-e10c-4f91-b2dd-74fae951c6d8/bazaart-edit-app.jpg" class="position-absolute t-0 l-0 h-100 w-100">
                    </div>

                    <!-- the below code will insert the previous and next photo arrows -->
                    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#photoCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                    </a>

                    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#photoCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                    </a>

                </div>
            </div> <!-- end carousel -->
        </div> <!-- end card 2 -->

        <!-- card 3 -->
        <div class="col-sm-4 card" style="Height: 350px">
            <div class="card-body small-tab-container">
                <h6 class="card-title">Upcoming Events</h6>

                <p>Some content</p>

            </div>
        </div> <!-- end card 3-->

    </div> <!-- end: row 1 -->


    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You suggestion resolves the issue - thank you very much. I am wondering if there is a more Bootstrap-way of accomplishing this rather than custom CSS.

Comment: I added the all the other utility classes, but kept the `object-fit` and `object-position` as I don't believe bootstrap has those...

Comment: Though if you don't want to use an external stylesheet at all, you could put that style directly on the `img` tags.